# Angular: ngOnInit() called in every navigation

Tags: angular, angular-router, ngoninit

I work with Angular 9 and I use RouterModule.
I read somewhere that ngOnInit() function called only one time between navigations,
I mean every component initialized only once (ngOnInit() function).
I found that is not true.

Example of my code:
First, **localhost/home loads HomeComponent** and the following ngOnInit() called:

```
  ngOnInit(): void
  {
    console.log('init home component');
  }
```

Then, in **HomeComponent** I use [routerLink] to navigate to **localhost/user**
which loads **UserComponent**, 
and the following ngOnInit() called:

```
  ngOnInit(): void
  {
    console.log('init user component');
  }
```

Finally, in **UserComponent** I use [routerLink] to navigate to **localhost/home**
which loads **HomeComponent** again,
and the following ngOnInit() called:

```
  ngOnInit(): void
  {
    console.log('init home component');
  }
```

As a result, HomeComponent **DOES** initialized again.
Am I missing something?
**Thank you!**

Comment: How many times `ngOnInit` is called will depend entirely on your component hierarchy. Can you provide a live demo

Answer (score 2):

Angular 9.x Components will reload with route navigation and will run the `ngOnInit()` when using the `OnInit` decorator.  There may be some rare exceptions to this when using route parameters; however, re-initializing is the standard behavior.  Modules and singleton services, on the other hand, are only initialized once.

For example, you can have [singleton] services load once (e.g. if you want variables to persist):

```js
// user.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
}
```

Ref: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

On a related note, while modules only load once, you can defer their loading to when the user accesses certain routes.  This is helpful for larger apps that might take a long time to initially load.  Lazy loading example:

```js
// xxx-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: () => import('./customers/customers.module').then(m => m.CustomersModule)
  }
];
```

Ref: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you navigate, and how your routes are configured. Say you have a route customer/addresses/edit and customer/addresses/view

The view and edit are child routes of addresses. You attach an id to them so you can fetch the address. Say you are in the view component, and you

router.navigate(['./edit', 33], {relativeTo: route});

it will not run ngOnInit of the address component. If you run

router.navigate(['customer/addresses/edit', 33]);

The whole component tree will be reloaded, and the ngOnInit methods will be called.